# overflow: hidden; not working on image inside grid

Tags: css, css-grid

I have an image inside of a grid, I want the image to fill the grid container, and hide any overflow, see code:

```
    <div class="serviceFlexChildLeft serviceGridImage">
      <img id="broadcastProductionImage1" src="content/images/homepage/broadcastProduction2.png">
      <img id="broadcastProductionImage2" src="content/images/homepage/broadcastProduction3.png">
      <div id="broadcastSlash"></div>
    </div>
```

```
.serviceGridImage {
    display: grid;
    height: 40rem;
    grid-template: 50% 50% / 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#broadcastProductionImage1 {
    object-fit: cover;
    justidy-self: center;
    align-self: center;
    grid-area: 1 / 1 / 2 / 2;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#broadcastProductionImage2 {
    object-fit: cover;
    justify-self: center;
    align-self: center;
    grid-area: 2 / 1 / 3 / 2;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

you can see I've tried putting `overflow: hidden` on both the image itself, and on the grid parent, neither seem to have any effect, I've used both `object-fit: cover;` and `min-width: 100%; min-height: 100%;` to attempt achieving my desired results, neither seems to yield what I want, it does appear to work once I define either `width` or `height` without the `min`, but those both mess up the images ability to dynamically scale and fit the container.

suggestions?

Comment: Any codepen or jsfiddle link so that we can see it clearer?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, that u set a `overflow: hidden` directly to your images, but overflow: hidden works differently.
For example you create a div with a height and a width and give it overflow: hidden, your images **inside** won't overlap anymore.


Of course you set `overflow:hidden` to your `.serviceGridImage` but this contains both images, so nothing is overflowing `.serviceGridImage` right now. Your images overflowing the grid, not the div.

You can fix your current problem if you give the images a max-height value.

```css
.serviceGridImage {
    display: grid;
    height: 40rem;
    grid-template: 50% 50% / 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#broadcastProductionImage1 {
    object-fit: cover;
    justify-self: center;
    align-self: center;
    grid-area: 1 / 1 / 2 / 2;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#broadcastProductionImage2 {
    object-fit: cover;
    justify-self: center;
    align-self: center;
    grid-area: 2 / 1 / 3 / 2;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.serviceGridImage img {
    max-height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="serviceFlexChildLeft serviceGridImage">
      <img id="broadcastProductionImage1" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1613470651441-9f59d6918dd6?ixid=MXwxMjA3fDB8MHxlZGl0b3JpYWwtZmVlZHw0fHx8ZW58MHx8fA%3D%3D&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60">
      <img id="broadcastProductionImage2" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1613465892991-39d8d5fb2d3a?ixid=MXwxMjA3fDB8MHxlZGl0b3JpYWwtZmVlZHw1fHx8ZW58MHx8fA%3D%3D&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60">
      <div id="broadcastSlash"></div>
    </div>
```

Or change your HTML structure like this:

```css
.serviceGridImage {
    display: grid;
    height: 40rem;
    grid-template: 50% 50% / 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.image {
  display: grid;
  grid-area: 1 / 1 / 2 / 2;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.image.second {
   grid-area: 2 / 1 / 3 / 2; 
}

#broadcastProductionImage1 {
    object-fit: cover;
    justify-self: center;
    align-self: center;
    
    overflow: hidden;
}

#broadcastProductionImage2 {
    object-fit: cover;
    justify-self: center;
    align-self: center;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="serviceFlexChildLeft serviceGridImage">
      <div class="image">
        <img id="broadcastProductionImage1" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1613470651441-9f59d6918dd6?ixid=MXwxMjA3fDB8MHxlZGl0b3JpYWwtZmVlZHw0fHx8ZW58MHx8fA%3D%3D&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60">
      </div>
      <div class="image second">
        <img id="broadcastProductionImage2" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1613465892991-39d8d5fb2d3a?ixid=MXwxMjA3fDB8MHxlZGl0b3JpYWwtZmVlZHw1fHx8ZW58MHx8fA%3D%3D&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60">
      </div>
      <div id="broadcastSlash"></div>
    </div>
```